# drupal 7 добавление способа оплаты

Tags: drupal, drupal7

Как добавить **способ оплаты**?  Вижу кнопку для добавления правила оплаты, а где же возможность добавить способ оплаты в друпале?

Нужно получить 3 варианта оплаты:

> наличными при доставке
>
> онлайн оплата
>
> оплата картой при получении

первые 2 способа сейчас уже есть, если включаю третий, то получается либо

> наличными при доставке
>
> наличными при доставке
>
> онлайн оплата

либо

> наличными при доставке
>
> онлайн оплата
>
> онлайн оплата

...*хуже друпала только umi cms, но разобраться с проблемой как-то нужно((*

[image]

[image]